# java jdk installation error, on windows, 32 bits

Tags: java

please can anyone help me with this installation error

> Error 1332. the cabinet file 'sj180600.cab' required for this
>   installation is corrupt and cannot be used. this could indicate a
>   network error, an error reading from the CD-ROM, or a problem with
>   this package

I got this error when trying to install the java jdk

Comment: re-download and start over. "corrupt and can not be used" means something went wrong with saving the file, before trying to install it.

Answer (score 0):

is not because of Issue in JDK setup or as such.

Some of the reasons may be:

Some research suggests that this problem may arise because of bad RAM.

Source - https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=65872

This is a Windows Installer error that may occur for different cabinet file names located on the installation media (usually on CD).

Source - error-1335-the-cabinet-file-filecab-required-for-this-installation-is-corrupt-and-cannot-be-used-this-could-indicate-a-network-error-an-error-reading-from-the-cd-rom-or-a-problem-with-this-package

Can be caused by User Access Control.

Source - http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/error-error-1335the-cabinet-file-data1cab-required-installation-corrupt-and-cannot-be-used-co

Corrupted installer caused by a firewall or virus software running on your computer.

Source - http://www.tomshardware.com/forum/7992-63-error-1335-help

Occur when the installer is unable to access the necessary files from the DVD/CD-ROM drive.

Source - http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/install-error-1311-1335-or.html

Each link has its own list of steps to resolve the Issue. Not sure what may be causing Issue in your case.

You can try different solutions and see if any one can help.

Thanks!!